# Scala/Spark parsing CYYMMDD date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, simpledateformat

Does Java SimpleDateFormat not support CYYMMDD? (I know, it's a horrible date format, take it up with IBM.)

Just to be clear, the date is a 7 byte string.  A 0 (zero) in the first byte means 20th century (19xx), a 1 (one) in the first byte means 21st century (20xx).

0201021 would be 1920-10-21

1201021 would be 2020-10-21.

`to_date($"<stupid_date_column>","cyyMMdd")` returns null.

Is my only alternative using Scala/Spark to substring out the first byte and an if/then to determine the century?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. And no, it doesn’t support that format. The bad news is that its modern replacement, `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) doesn’t either.